# how many vectors are there in this vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra

I am very much new to vector spaces.

I have a question from an exercise of finite Vector space hamlos. Can any one help me understand this question further,

If $p$ is a prime, then $\Bbb Z_p^n$ is a vector space over $\Bbb Z_p$.how many vectors are there in this vector space.

I am totally confused with this vector space, please help me.If this is posted in wrong place please tell me the correct place to post this.

Comment: $\mathbf Z_p$ (or $\mathbf F_p$) is the field with $p$ elements. So  where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}_{p}^n$ have $p^n$ elements (by set theory )so also $p^n$ vector and the dimension of $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^n$ is n since $\{e_i\}$ is a basis when $e_i=(0,0...1,0,0,...)$ when the 1 is in the i place

Comment: What is $e_i$  supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

This proof gives in to a simple combinatorial argument. $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is nothing but the field with $p$ elements. $\mathbb{Z^n_p}$ is the set of all n-tuples with co-ordinates in the field.
Put in other words, there are $n$ blanks and $p$ ways to fill each blank, hence the vector space contains $p^n$ elements. 
Checking that each element of the vector space is covered this way and each element here is indeed a member of $\mathbb{Z^n_p}$ is trivial.